# index.html not showing up. ( nodejs / docker / nginx )

Tags: html, node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

Good evening every one:

I'm learning how to build a docker container with nginx and nodejs.

I'm stuck at the moment, I got to a point that everthing is working but some how the index.html page is not showning what get pushed by the nodeJS container.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    image: arm64v8/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "433:433"
    volumes:
      - /home/user/setup-ssl-nginx-docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - node_app

  node_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: node_app
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
        - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
        - .:/node-1
```

docker-compose.yml

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location / {
        autoindex on;
        proxy_pass http://node_app:5001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install express
COPY . . 
EXPOSE 5001
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Dockerfile

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express();
const path = require(`path`);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.get('app', (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send({ "message": "App Response from Server-1"});
}); 

const port = 5001

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server is Up & running on port ${port}`))
```

app.js file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Welkom</p>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

I'm getting a blanco index.html, if I run docker log it shows both container is running fine NodeJS & nginx.

if I do a wget domain.com im also getting the blank html back.

Answer (score 0):

Im not completly sure, but maybe give it a try.

You might adjust your `docker-compose.yml` to the following:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    image: arm64v8/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "433:433"
    volumes:
      - /home/user/setup-ssl-nginx-docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - node_app
    networks:    # Add this
      - net_nginx

  node_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: node_app
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:    # EDIT THIS
        - 5001    # EDIT THIS
    volumes:
        - .:/node-1
    networks:    # Add this
      - net_nginx

networks:    # Add this
  net_nginx:
```

My idea is, that with `ports: -5001:5001` you just expose this port to the host machine. So you access it on the machine on port 5001. I don't know exactly if you can really access that port from another docker container that way.

So we don't use `ports` and instead `expose`, that exposes the given port to all internal docker networks the container is attached to. So we place the container inside the `net_nginx` network together with the nginx container, so nginx is able to find the container and access it via the given port.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried but html is still not showing up sadly.

Comment: Have you tried your own configuration (`docker-compose.yml`) on your own computer and accessed port 5001 to test, if the html file is served there? Or opened the port on the machine and tried to access it there?

Comment: I'm doing that now as we speak so, I will let you know.

Comment: Minor adjustments that shouldn't change the outcome: inside your `Dockerfile` you should use `COPY package*.json ./` to copy both the `package.json` and the `package-lock.json`. Afterwards you should just run the command `RUN npm install` so every package from the `package.json` gets installed. Also you should add a `.dockerignore` file in the same folder the `Dockerfile` is in and at least write `node_modules` inside, so that folder get ignored by the copy command, because the `npm install` command will create that folder itself.

Comment: Let me know when you tested the port thing and can maybe give some logs from `docker compose logs` :)